# It always create a nother file

Tags: saving

[image]

As you can see on the picture it always create another file. I have no idea what this file is for. Also strange is that it is not called Blender File but Blend1 File.
Thanks for our help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blend1 files are your previous manual saves. This is so that if something goes catastrophically wrong with the most recent file (and that you can't fix it), you can load up previous manual saves (Blend1 files).

If you wish to disable this:

Go to Edit > User Preferences
Then go to the "Save & Load" tab.
Reduce the number of "Save Versions" to 0.

Comment: Thank you for our help